# iOS - change a view's content on push notification received event

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm coming from Android development background. In Android you send a push notification and then you handle the rest using a service (creating the actual system notification, modifying app's content, etc).

As far as I know, when sending iOS push notifications, it automatically creates a system notification for you in the notification center based on your message payload. After searching here and on google, I think I have to use application:didReceiveRemoteNotification event to add/remove a view's content. How can I access the push notification's content so I can put it in the app as well (I want to display the message in the app even if the user has dismissed the notification in the notification center)? There will be another message later on (usually the same day) to remove the message from the app.

I understand that the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification method won't be called if the app is closed, so I will have to use some other event (like didfinishlaunching) to get the message. But how do I access the push notification's message itself?

Comment: See "Handling Local And Remove Notifications" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4

Comment: And "The Notification Payload" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Comment: thanks Jeff. I think im able to get the contents of the push notification through userInfo NSDictionary object that is being passed to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to display the message in the app even if the user has dismissed the notification in the notification center

This can't be done. iOS passes the notification data to your app only if the user opens the app from the notification center. If the user dismisses the notification and later launches the app, the only way for the app to get this data is to retrieve in from your server.

As for getting the notification data if the app is launched from the notification center, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968578/calling-didreceiveremotenotification-when-app-is-launching-for-the-first-time/).

Comment: what if I save the data to a file on the device and retrieve it when it opens up? I suppose it will work? I just don't want to be checking the server all the time to minimize bandwidth use.

Comment: or save it to sql database?

Comment: @yash As of iOS6 you can't get the notification data if you dismiss the notification. Any code that you write (for saving the data) will only be executed after the user opens the app - either from the notification center or from the launch icon in the home screen. Only in the former case the notification data will be passed to your code.